# Transpose of matrix is sending Error in C

Tags: c

There are two 2D  arrays and `r` and `c` are their row and column, `i` and `j` are used for integer variables.

Transpose of matrix is running well till the value `r` and `c` are entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a[50][50], b[50][50], i, j, r, c;

    printf("Enter the value of R and c");
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {  
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? I've just compiled and run it, and the code works fine here.

Comment: https://ideone.com/0vwLy2

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it waits for you to enter values or closes the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a[50][50], b[50][50], i, j, r, c;

    printf("Enter the value of R and c\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
           scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }


    }

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        printf("%3d",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
  printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", a[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nil your code is working.It is so helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are not "transposing" the matrix. You are simply copying one array to another. To transpose a matrix, you need to convert rows to columns:

```
  for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            b[j][i]=a[i][j];
        }
    }
```

and reverse `c` and `r` in the loop condition when printing:

```
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note that your arrays are capable of handling 50x50. So you need to ensure the input values of `r` and `c` don't exceed these limits.

Comment: Why do you reverse `c` and `r` when printing if you have transposed the matrix? Those are square matrix.

Comment: @Bob__ If you have a matrix `[1 2 3]` ( read: left to right) with r=1 and c=3 then after transposing, it becomes `[1 2 3]` (read: top to bottom) and  r=3 and c=1. So it's necessary to reverse. A matrix doesn't have to square to transpose it.